# "+" and "-" not aligned in tikz in multiple math fonts

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, alignment, math-fonts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (2,2);
    \draw (0,0) node[left] {$+$};
    \draw (0,0) node[right] {$-+$};
    \draw (0,1) node[left] {$\times$};
    \draw (0,1) node[right] {$\div$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have tested this in `newtxmath` `newpxmath` `fontsetup(NewCM)` `Libertinus Math` `Cambria Math` `TeX Gyre Termes/Pagella/Schola Math` `STIX Two Math` `XITS Math` `Latin Modern Math + Unicode Math`

And they all produce this:

[image]

Only if I use no math font package at all will `+` and `-` aligned.

[image]

Also, if I add something before/after `$-$`, will it be aligned.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the complete minimal code required to reproduce the problem. Code fragments are rarely helpful. That's especially true in a question of this kind. Please also specify which engine you're using or report whether it depends on which engine you use.

Answer (score 7):

This is because Ti*k*Z uses `center` as an anchor when placing nodes by default. In the case of `left` or `right`, this is adjusted horizontally but not vertically.

In `newtxmath`, minus is essentially in a box with space at the bottom but not the top.

[image: boxes around plus and minus in newtxmath]

As far as TeX is concerned, everything is just a box. Perhaps influenced by the later Wittgenstein, it doesn't know or care what is in the box. The problem of laying out the page is just a matter of assembling boxes.

In Computer or Latin Modern, that box containing the minus is symmetrical i.e. the same amount of space above and below the minus.

[image: boxes around Latin Modern plus and minus]

This means that `center` *happens* to align the visible minus with the horizontal bar of the plus. But this is just coincidence and there's no reason to expect this behaviour in general.

If you want to align things on the baseline (default outside the `tikzpicture` environment), you just need to tell Ti*k*Z to do so.

[image: aligned plus and minus with newtxmath]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,draw,ultra thin}]
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (2,2);
  \draw (0,0) node (plus)[left] {$+$};
  \draw (plus.base east) node[anchor=base west] {$-$};
  \draw (0,1) node[left] {$\times$};
  \draw (0,1) node[right] {$\div$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basically, fonts are designed so that the characters are correctly positioned relative to the baseline. When you put, say, a `$+-$` into a Ti*k*Z node, you set up a baseline for those characters, so the minus and plus will also happen to end up with their combined centre on the grid line. This happens because plus is symmetrical - not the visible glyph, but the glyph-in-the-box.

[image: plus-minus aligned as it happens]

But when you put them in separate nodes, each node gets its own baseline. Since the plus-box has the same space above and below the horizontal line, it happens to be centred on the grid line. Since the minus-box has more space below than above, the minus floats above the grid line.

Comment: Thanks, I test this to more fonts and I found that most math fonts use the half-height box for minus sign and blace it at the top of the box.

Comment: Using the `base` anchor allows for correct alignment. The `mid` anchor allows this too (p.238, tikz manual).

Comment: But it is weird that `\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` is different from not using unicode-math. It will use the half-height box.

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu Not really. Unicode maths is a very different creature and it's not surprising things the boxes might be adjusted since the ways in which things have to fit together are rather different.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. True. I'd forgotten that. But I think `base` is easier in this case to understand because the baseline in text and maths outside `tikzpicture` is a familiar concept (or at least fairly intelligible), whereas `mid` is rather less so. However, `mid` might be a better choice if you were forced to create the minus node first.

Comment: I'm surprised that the newtxmath minus does not seem to be centered on the math axis. If that is really so, then I would consider it a problem in the font.

Comment: @mickep I think the minus is centred on the maths axis when it's typeset, but Ti*k*Z doesn't use that information. It just takes the centre of the bounding box. I'm not exactly sure why it is done that way in the font - it doesn't seem to be so in Latin Modern type 1, for example - but it won't affect the typeset results when TeX typesets maths or text, I don't think. The problem inside the node, I think, is that there isn't an independent baseline or maths axis to align to. (But I'm not certain this explanation is correct.)

Comment: @mickep Some fonts, like newtxmath/newpxmath, may be designed that the minus sign not in the middle, but lower. Test `8 - 0 = 8` as an example.

Comment: I do not have those fonts installed, but I trust @cfr that they are centered and that it is the way they were invoked by tikz that was the reason for non-alignment this time. If it was the font, I guess the picky TeXies would have complained long ago. :)